# Magento 2 not sending emails

Tags: email, magento, smtp, magento2

I'm having an issue with magento not sending any emails. I've already tested some solutions and it's not worked.

I'm using a SMTP extension and Magento 2.2.6: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp
And always getting an error when testing the extensions configs:
[image]

Comment: I think this question is better suited for the Magento Stackexchange or the Mageplaza support as there are potentially thousands of reasons why it does not work. Most likely it is either another extension interfereing with SMTP (like PDF Extensions, Mailtemplates etc.) or your server config that prevents a successful connection, but without any errorlogs or similar it is impossible to say. Check magento-root/var/log/ for errors.

Comment: @Tobi Thank you for your reply. I've checked log folder and the only modified file is system.log and no errors were found

Comment: Not sure if it's something with the extension because I had no success with the test using a php script.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. My host provider (Digital Ocean) was blocking outgoing mails. I conctacted them and I was able to test successfully and send emails.